# How do I make scaled image not go past its container

Tags: javascript, html, css, scale

I'm trying to make an image within a container not soar past 15px from the bottom of the container when it is scaled larger. What is the best way to do this? I've messed around with getBoundingClientRect() and such but haven't found the key to doing it. Here is an example of my problem.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var img = document.getElementById('image');

    img.style.WebkitTransform = ('scaleY(2.0)');
    img.style.width = img.getBoundingClientRect().width + 'px';
    img.style.width = img.getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px';
}
```

```css
.rand {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:15px;
    left:45%;
}

div#test {
    margin:auto;
    border:2px solid red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    object-fit: contain;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>
    <img id='image' class='rand' src = 'https://www.purebuttons.com/cp/Pure_Buttons/html/images/squareprev.png'>
    </div>
   
    <button onclick='myFunction()'>CLICK</button>
</body>
```

So have the image fully be scaled larger and smaller but still sitting at 15px from bottom, and not go lower once scaled. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is it always going to be the same distance from the bottom? i.e. it starts at 15px from the bottom before scaling, never higher?

Comment: Adding `margin-bottom: 15px;` to rand might be what you want.

Comment: @Ry- yeah so in the example, the bottom the square never goes below 15px from the bottom of the container AFTER scaling. So it still scales fully, but just like "up" if you know what i mean.

Comment: @TimHunter Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to set the transform to start from the bottom with `transform-origin`:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var img = document.getElementById('image');

    img.style.transform = 'scale(2.0)';
}
```

```css
.rand {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 45%;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
}

#test {
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>
    <img id='image' class='rand' src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxTTq.png'>
</div>
   
<button onclick='myFunction()'>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the attributes you can change the class to play with the position.

```js
function myFunction() 
{
    var img = document.getElementById('image');

    //img.style.WebkitTransform = ('scaleY(2.0)');
    img.className = 'rand2';
}
```

```css
.rand 
{
    
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    
    bottom:15px;
    left:45%;
    
    border:1px solid red;
}

.rand2
{
    
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    
    transform: scaleY(2.0);
    
    bottom:35px;
    left:45%;
    
    border:1px solid red;
}

div#test {
    margin:auto;
    border:2px solid red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    object-fit: contain;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Right, but my scale factor is going to different depending on other variables, so it would be best done in javascript. Is there a way to store the length/width of a scaled image as a variable without actually displaying the image scaled. Because then I could make it's height/width those stored variables and that would solve it.

Comment: You can add it to the "name" property when you first loaded. No matter what you scaled you can always read the originals from there.